# Why does my AND or WHERE clause not work?

Tags: mysql

I do have a query on four tables. For readability I changed the table names to `t` and the coloumns to `col`.

If I don't add the second-last line, the query runs as it should. Nice.

But when I want to exclude entries where `col4` has the value of `x`, it doesn't work. When using `AND ...` it seems like it just ignores that `AND ...`. While using `WHERE ...` I get an empty result.

```
SELECT      t1.col1,
            t2.col2,
            t3.col3, 
            t4.col4
FROM        t2ble1 t1
LEFT JOIN   t2ble2 t2 
ON          t1.col1 = t2.col1 
LEFT JOIN   table3 t3
ON          t3.col1 = t1.col1 
LEFT JOIN   table4 t4
ON          t4.col1 = t1.col1
AND t4.col4 <> "x"
LIMIT 10;"
```

To exclude the error that I may have too many `x` in the database and my `LIMIT` will skip them, I only have one record of `x`. Still this record with value `x` will show up while using `AND ...`.

**May someone please explain to me where my error is to exclude records with** `col4 = "x"`**?**

---

For clarification:

I want to SELECT from `t1`. This data should show up 1x in the result.

Rows from `t1` get additional data from `t2` and `t3` (always connected through one ID and only one line per `t1`-row).

If `t4.col4 = "x"` then the whole row should not be in the result at all.

`exampleT1 | exampleT2 | exampleT3 | asdf` -> yes

`exampleT1 | exampleT2 | exampleT3 | x` -> nope

---

**Second edit:**

If I don't put any WHERE/AND/blablabla with x, this is the result (see at the rightest coloumn this mischievious x):

[image]

When I use excludes for x, I just get NULL - **but I want the whole row to disappear**:

[image]

Comment: As currently written, the join to t4 will fail when col4 is "x", but all the other joins may still succeed. If you changed that to a `WHERE` clause, you're implicitly changing that LEFT JOIN to be an INNER JOIN, again where the value is not "x". It's not clear whether you want a NULL in col4 to be in the result set, or not?

Comment: are you sure there's not a special character or space in t4.col4?  What happens if you set it = "x" do you get any record back? or "X" is case sensitivity turned on?  my guess is it's working fine, the data in the column just isn't what you expect.

Comment: Switching it to a `=` doesn't change anything on the result - I also looked up for the case-sensitivy. So I guess Rowland is on the right way... For clarification: There doesn't have to be any record in `t4` that fits - thats why I got the `LEFT JOIN`. But if there IS a record in `t4`, I want the whole line to not show up in the result.

Comment: I'm confused in the results you're getting, you see a column t4.col4 containing "X" when limiting to 10 records.  when you have `and t4.col4 <> "x"`.  That's impossible given the above joins unless there's a bug in mySQL (which I doubt in this instance).  T4.col4 can't therfore be "x"

Comment: Now I'm confused, too. :D My intention is to JOIN all 4 tables but only show results where `col4 <> "x"`. (I guess the short way sounds more simple. :) )

Comment: I guess I need to see data and expected results: I setup a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e754e5/3/0) trying to reproduce your problem, but no luck; I guess I need better sample data...

Comment: how about this... `Select count(*) from t4 where col4="x"` any results?  now the inverse but lets display col4 so you can inspect. `Select * from t4 where col4 <> "x"` any records look like X in col4? if there are, then I believe the problem is data. You have a hidden character making it not just X...  but back to your statement "But when I want to exclude entries where col4 has the value of x, it doesn't work" what doens't work? you don't get records from table1,2,3 when it is not X?

Comment: Tested to SELECT, I get the right results (only x or no x). And I don't get why I there is 3x `T1A` in `T1COL1` in your fiddle... oh man, I so do need weekend!

Comment: I edited my question to add clarification. I hope that worked as intended.

Comment: Breaking news! I guess my whole query is a bit wrong. When I delete the `AND/WHERE` clause, it shows all records in the result, even with `x` - as intended. When adding it back again, it also shows all records, but instead of an `x` that coloumn got `NULL`. But I want the whole row then to disappear... I guess I have to look over JOINs that weekend again...

Comment: Aaaand another edit, this time with example pictures. As you see, it adds a NULL field instead of removing the whole line. I develop an acersion to Xs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of a comparison with `NULL` is also `NULL`, so as a `WHERE` condition, you implicitly throw away the rows where that was no record in `t4`, instead, you can `COALESCE` to always have a non-null value to do your comparison, and you'll always get a true result.

So something like:

```
SELECT      t1.col1,
            t2.col2,
            t3.col3, 
            t4.col4
FROM        t2ble1 t1
LEFT JOIN   t2ble2 t2 
ON          t1.col1 = t2.col1 
LEFT JOIN   table3 t3
ON          t3.col1 = t1.col1 
LEFT JOIN   table4 t4
ON          t4.col1 = t1.col1
WHERE       COALESCE(t4.col4, '') <> 'x'
LIMIT 10;
```

In this case, I've coalesced to a hard-coded empty string, but you could use any value other than 'x' and it'd work for what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! Unfortunetally, it doesn't change my result as I want to... I added a second edit to my Question Of Doom to ensure my deeds: If there is a sinister `x` in the last row (`link`), I want the whole line of date (in this example `NETFOR350_HHN` as ID) to disappear.

Comment: Your screenshot shows that behaviour, with this code, or it would if it was a `WHERE` clause, like my example?

Comment: Both. You can see it's like your code, but I did change "t" and "col" for other names, as they have been used for clarity. Or did I misunderstood something?

Comment: You also changed a `WHERE` (which will filter results) for an `AND` on a join, which will only affect that join. That's the key difference, and why yours doesn't work.

Comment: Oh that little son of a `WHERE`... Tried it again and it works now as intended. Thanks for that! :)

Comment: Okay, I've found an anomaly: I `LIMIT 10`. Now if there is a col4 with `x` in it, it gives an empty row - but this one counts to the LIMIT, too. So for example I get 10 rows, but 3 of them are empty strings. How to filter them out so that the LIMIT is not affected? (Do you need any further information?)